# ESP32: nodemcu lua, is it support threads

Tags: multithreading, lua, esp32, nodemcu

I have search thru nodemcu docs, not find anything about threads support in ESP32 DEV version.
Does someone know if it was done, or working on it?

Comment: Since this chip can't run code in parallel anyways [Coroutines](https://www.lua.org/pil/9.1.html) may be sufficient

Comment: are you sure, there is threads support in micropython, it works very well

Comment: Yes, the chip does not has multiple cores. Correct me if I'm wrong, I'm not an expert. This doesn't stop you from using threads, especially if you use IO operations you would still benefit from them, but they still run sequential.
Lua itself has no threads, the common way to add them is to launch multiple Lua instances. But since Coroutines are easier and are sometimes sufficient, I wanted to suggest that first :)

Comment: "CPU: Xtensa dual-core".  as I said, it is realized in micropython. I can use many threads as long as free memory exists.

Comment: My bad, mixed up the chips! I had the ESP8266 in mind. You can use many threads, but only 2 will run at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

currently LUA do not support threads and is not working on that yet.

Answer (score 0):

At least it is possible with another lua firmware "[Lua-RTOS-ESP32](https://github.com/whitecatboard/Lua-RTOS-ESP32)", have a look at the nice documentation: [THREAD module](https://github.com/whitecatboard/Lua-RTOS-ESP32/wiki/Thread-Module)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).